# Streetview not rendering properly in firefox browser

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Here is the fiddle i worked on http://jsfiddle.net/fyDkD/14/

My **HTML** is here

```
<div id="map-holder">
  <div id="map_canvas" class="bigmap"></div>
  <div id="map_stv" class="minimap" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

My **CSS** is here

```
#map-holder {
    height: 1200px ;
    position: relative;
    }

.bigmap{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.minimap{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

#map_stv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#map_stv img {
    border: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

In this i see that when we drag and drop the pegman anywhere on the google map then we get the streetview. The street view is not proper only in Firefox browser. Also i have seen that if the difference between width and height is considerably large then we can see the issue very easily. The img of street view is not showing properly. Please suggest on this.

Comment: Are you talking about the weird distorted sky in street view? I see that too, in Firefox only. I think your hunch is right that the very tall and narrow street view has something to do with it. Not sure what I can suggest as a fix, though, other than to file a bug with Google on the [Maps API bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

Comment: @MichaelGeary ATleast some one agrees with me. Cheers mate :D

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by adding
    `mode: 'html5'`
to the panoramaOptions. I tested it and it works.

See Google's answer to this this bug report I sent them:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7246